# Splitting a Pandas DataFrame column into two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a simple web scrape, DataFrame project. I have a simple 8x1 DataFrame, and I'm trying to split it into an 8x2 DataFrame. So far this is what my DataFrame looks like:

```
dframe = DataFrame(data, columns=['Active NPGL Teams'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

```
    Active NPGL Teams
1   Baltimore Anthem (2015–present)
2   Boston Iron (2014–present)
3   DC Brawlers (2014–present)
4   Los Angeles Reign (2014–present)
5   Miami Surge (2014–present)
6   New York Rhinos (2014–present)
7   Phoenix Rise (2014–present)
8   San Francisco Fire (2014–present)
```

I would like to add a column, "Years Active" and split the "(2014-present)",    "(2015-present)" into the "Years Active" column.  How do I split my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
dframe['Active NPGL Teams'].str.split(r' (?=\()', expand=True)
```

```
                    0               1
1    Baltimore Anthem  (2015–present)
2         Boston Iron  (2014–present)
3         DC Brawlers  (2014–present)
4   Los Angeles Reign  (2014–present)
5         Miami Surge  (2014–present)
6     New York Rhinos  (2014–present)
7        Phoenix Rise  (2014–present)
8  San Francisco Fire  (2014–present)
```

The key is the regex `r' (?=\()'` which matches a space only if it is followed by an open parenthesis (lookahead assertion).

---

Another approach (which is about 5% slower but more flexible) is to user `Series.str.extract`.

```
dframe['Active NPGL Teams'].str.extract(r'^(?P<Team>.+) (?P<YearsActive>\(.+\))$',
                                        expand=True)
```

```
                 Team     YearsActive
1    Baltimore Anthem  (2015–present)
2         Boston Iron  (2014–present)
3         DC Brawlers  (2014–present)
4   Los Angeles Reign  (2014–present)
5         Miami Surge  (2014–present)
6     New York Rhinos  (2014–present)
7        Phoenix Rise  (2014–present)
8  San Francisco Fire  (2014–present)
```

Comment: Love this! Marvelous! :) Didn't know about this `pandas` feature yet.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I would of never figured that out.